# Why am I getting a NoSuchFileException when running readAllBytes on this file

Tags: java, android, file, path

I am trying to make a simple android app that uses OpenAPLR

http://doc.openalpr.com/cloud_api.html

So I copied the code under the Java section on how to make a REST api request and put it all into onClick method of a button and took a picture of a license plate and saved it as license_plate.jpg in the location

app/res/drawable/license_plate.jpg

But whenever I run the application I always get an error pointing to these lines

```
Path path = Paths.get("drawable/license_plate.jpg");
byte[] data = Files.readAllBytes(path);
```

java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: drawable/license_plate.jpg

Where should I be saving this image so I can use it during the application? 
And where should I be saving images used for future applications when I am not just using a single picture I have already preloaded?

Comment: Give the complete path (app/...) and try. If it works then your relative path needs fixing based on where this image file is i relation to running app/file

Comment: I have tried right clicking on license_plate.jpg in the file viewer in android studio and selected "Copy Path" and "Copy Relative Path" and put both of those in Paths.get() and got the same NoSuchFileException error

Answer (score 0):

> You give wrong path. You can only save a picture  in your device and
>   then give image folder path for example :

```
Path path = Paths.get("/storage/projects/alpr/samples/testing/car1.jpg");
byte[] data = Files.readAllBytes(path);
```

Comment: So I can't put an image anywhere in my original android studio project and access it in my application? I have to put it in a folder on my phone to use it?

Comment: Uri.parse("android.resource://"+BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID+"/" + R.drawable.license_plate.jpg);

Comment: i think you can use like this                                                                                   Path path = Paths.get(Uri.parse("android.resource://"+BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID+"/" + R.drawable.license_plate.jpg));